# Most effective way to implement problem based on large sequence and xor operation

Tags: python, xor

I have been given the following input:

1. n where n is size of sequence
2. k is an integer
3. a sequence A[0] A[1] A[2] ............A[n-1]

I need to perform for each i from 0 to (k-1) inclusive

```
   find a,b
   where a=A[i%n] and b=A[n-(i%n)-1]
   then set A[i%n]=a XOR b
```

and output the final sequence space separated

Order is given :-

```
 n<=10^4
 k<=10^12
 Ai<=10^7 for each i
```

> i have applied the naive approach

```
n,k=map(int,input().split())
arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
for i in range(k):
    t=i%n
    arr[t]=arr[t]^arr[n-(t)-1]
for i in arr:
    print(i,end=" ")
```

but it shows Time Limit exceeded for large test cases.

Would like an efficient implementation suggestion for the above

Comment: I think this answer belongs to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: They denied to suggest new implementation , said it is place to get the current code reviewed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**

> Re:Updated implementation approach for the problem

**

After combining algorithm suggested my

> @AJNeufeld and @vujazzman

Sequence remains same if loop is run up to any multiple of `(N*3)`

so we can save the overhead of running for all values of `k`

Rather find the closest multiple of `(n*3) to K` and then `run loop for remaining value from the found multiple to k`

Note:- Odd number `n` case to be handled separately in advance by `set A[n//2] = 0`

so i have came up with the following implementation:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n,k=map(int,input().split())
    arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
    if n % 2 and k > n//2 :           #odd n case
        arr[ n//2 ] = 0
    rem= k % ( 3*n )
    closest_multiple_3n = ( k-rem )
    for i in range( closest_multiple_3n,k ):
        t=i % n
        arr[t] ^= arr[-1-t]
    print(*arr)
```

i have created some self made test cases like :-

```
t=1
n=11 k=9999999998
A[] = 20 7 27 36 49 50 67 72 81 92 99

output:- 20 7 27 36 49 0 67 72 81 92 119

note :- closest_multiple_3n = 9999999966
         rem = 32
        (20^92=119)
```

It works perfectly now in less than 1 sec